# Trying to get a hover Property that puts the hover bar in the bottom

Tags: css

I am currently having difficulties trying to get a bar I made using hover to appear in the a element bottom instead of the top, do you guys have any suggestions? I am new with CSS and been googling for the better part of 2 hours and cannot find a solution.

Heres the code I am using

```
html: 

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Third</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fourth</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fifth</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sixth</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Seventh</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Eighth</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Ninth</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<body>
</body>
</html>

CSS: 

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

nav {
    background-color: red;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 0;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav li {

    height: 40px;
    padding: inherit;
}
nav li:hover {
    background-color: white;
    height: 5px;
}
nav a {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
          float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 18px 12px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `height` of `nav li`, just set the padding of `li` and add `border-bottom` color to the hovered element. Also remove the padding of `nav li a`

```css
nav {
    background-color: red;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 0;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav li {

/*     height: 40px; */
   
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
nav li:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}
nav a {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
          float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1;
/*     padding: 18px 12px; */
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Third</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fourth</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fifth</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sixth</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Seventh</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Eighth</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Ninth</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. I was eating my head trying to work around it.